# Stopping IP adresses and Subdomains, Only Domains are allowed

Tags: php, subdomain

I want to stop all the IPs and subdomains completely. Someone edit/modify it so it won't add IPs and subdomains into database. I only want main (Top-Leven Domain) in my database. Here's the pattern i am using:

```
$pattern = '/^(([\w]+:)?\/\/)?(([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,4}(:[\d]+)?(\/([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(\?(&amp;?([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?$/';

if (preg_match($pattern, $url) ) {
header("Location: good.php");
} else {
header("Location: bad.php");
die();
}
```

Comment: So what is that pattern matching at the moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A toplevel domain only contains letters. Here is [a list of TLDs](http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt).

I assume you meant to say 'second level domains', but even that will give you trouble. For instance, `.co.uk` is a very popular SLD, but it is not used for a website or anything. The domains you mention, are on the third level, below this SLD. (anycompanywebsite.co.uk).

So, what I'm saying is that you cannot do this using a simple regex. You will need to have a list of second, third and even fourth levels that are used as if they are a TLD.

Comment: oh, so .co.uk and other domains will also blocked :( then what's the best solution/code or do i need to use Parse_url function instead of this pattern?

Comment: Well, it depends on the purpose. Subdomains can be very different from domains. They can point to another IP addres for instance. So you should wonder if you really don't want them in your database. If that is indeed the case, you will need a comprehensive list of TLDs to check by. If you are goiing to allow subdomains (at least for now), all you need to do, is check that the entered value is not an ip address. Note that domains can be numbers too, depending on the TLD. Only the TLD itself is always text (for now).

Comment: By domains being a number, I meant the second level domain, for instance http://9292.nl

Comment: hi, I searched over the internet and got this new pattren which only allow 2-4 character/letters subdomain e.g. google.co.uk or google.com.au but its working with www. and not working without www. How do i edit the pattern: "/^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]+[a-z0-9](\.[a-z]{2,4})+$/i"

Comment: You can't. It's all fun and games, but checking for length won't help you. check `www.ns.nl` verses `abc.co.uk`, they have the same pattern. And don't forget `parliament.uk`, which is also not a website itself, but a domain under which to add subdomains.

Comment: oops...... looks like, i need to hire a programmer now to block all these unwanted subdomains and IPs.. can u help?